# Failing to drop or truncate a table

Tags: mysql, truncate

I tried every thing to truncate a table, but I always have the same message :

```
Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`mybdd`.`c_member`, CONSTRAINT `fk_cm_c_id` FOREIGN KEY (`c_id`) REFERENCES `comment` (`c_id`))
```

Looking some posts on this site I tried this :

ALTER TABLE `comment`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `c_member` FOREIGN KEY (`c_id`) 
      REFERENCES `comment` (`c_id`);

But it doens't work :

Can't create table 'mybdd.#sql-2ee0_3769864' (errno: 150){"success":false,"error":"

## 1005 - Can't create table 'sameditrbdd.#sql-2ee0_3769864' (errno: 150)</div>"}

How can I do that ?

Comment: You need to delete your mydd table first to avoid foreign key problem.

Comment: You need to REMOVE the foreign key constraint from the `mybdd` table.

Comment: Yes I deleted the table, but I still doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

You need to delete all references to the table, including all foreign key constraints and indexes, before you can drop a table.

Foreign key constraints can also prevent you from deleting specific rows.

Alternatively, you can turn off foreign key checks, but then setting them back on again will likely result in errors or unpredictable behavior (because your constraints are violated by the data in the data base).

Comment: How do I delete all references to the table ?

Comment: @Newben - You can use `ALTER TABLE DROP FOREIGN KEY ...` to drop a foreign constraint that another table has that references something in the table you want to drop. (This has to be a separate `ALTER TABLE` statement.) You need to know, of course, what constraints reference anything in your table.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
SET foreign_key_checks = 0;
DROP <your_table>
SET foreign_key_checks = 1;
```

Comment: I don't think it is a good idea. Some mydd table fields will be linked to nothing after your suggestion

Comment: Yes it's just a one of general solutions. Usually you would have to remove constraints alltogether which may suit you better

Comment: I've added semicolons, try now

Comment: @Edga, I have now this message : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`campaign`
SET foreign_key_checks = 1' at line 1

Comment: I tried this SET foreign_key_checks = 0;
DROP `campaign`
SET foreign_key_checks = 1; and this SET foreign_key_checks = 0;
DROP campaign
SET foreign_key_checks = 1;

Answer (score 0):

Very likely some people or their process holding your table hostage!!!

You should try to kill them addressing them by their spid #!

To see who is holding your table hostage, you open up your query analyser to run

```
execute sp_who2 'active' -- under the database of interest
```

Then, make your own judgment whether it is OK to kill them or not, or call those who logged in.

To kill, just do

```
kill 999 -- your spid # found in that table returned by above command
```

After that, try to truncate or drop again!

Best luck!!!